# how to resize images inside a div inside another div with css?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to only resize images that are in a div with a specific class, inside an other div with an other specific class. but the images which are only inside the div which is inside the other div should not be resized.

This works if I want to resize images inside a classed div:

```
div.classname>img { width:something; }
```

but this doesn't work:

```
div.classname2 > div.classname > img { width:something; }
```

**Markup**

```
<div class="classname2">
    <div class="classname">
        <img>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I can't refer to it with the inside class name.

So, to make it really clear, i need to resize these images:

```
<div class="classname2">
    <div class="classname">
        <img>
    </div>
</div>
```

But not these:

```
<div class="classname">
    <img>
</div>
```

Comment: In case answers are helpful, please consider upvoting them to be thankful of time and effor people invest to solve your problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like your css rule should work

```
div.classname2 > div.classname > img { width:something; }
```

Does this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhuf22xg/) show what you're trying to illustrate? If so, perhaps you just have overriding CSS rules somewhere?

Comment: oh. thank you, turns out i was just dumb as hell. it wasnt a 'div', but an 'a'. but putting only the class names there made it work.

Comment: np. It happens to the best of us  º¿º

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work

**CSS**

```
.classname2 .classname img { width: 200px; }
```

Comment: i think that would only work if the image itself had those classes. and after trying, it really doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Having:

```
<div class="parentDiv">
    <img class="img1">
    <div class="childDiv">
        <img class="img2">
    </div>
</div>
```

do it like this:

```
.parentDiv > img { width: 100px }
```

will just effect `<img>`s having `class="img1"` not those having `class="img2"`

Comment: that would be what i need though. i need to use the "parentDiv" to change the "img2" since i dont want to change all the "img2"s that are in childDiv but not parentDiv. i need to only change images which are in both

Comment: What do u mean by **I dont want to change all the "img2"s that are in childDiv but not parentDiv**. please be simple in english and say what is desired output?

Comment: there are images which are only in the inner div, and there are ones which are in both. i only want to change ones in both

Comment: I edited your question to add some code. please consider revising that code to fully convey the concept behind your question. at the moment I believe it is impossible for anyone with IQ lower than 140 to understand whats your desired output. please add meaningfull code to ur question

Comment: sorry, turns out it wasnt a 'div' but an 'a'. putting only the class names there solved it. thank you though

Answer (score 0):

Edit the only the single image you want without changing the rest, by going to that specific tag and putting the following style attributes.

```
<img class = "example" style = "width: 50px !important;">
```

**UPDATE**

Give this a try, add "!important" to the inside class to override the parent.

```
div.classname2 > div.classname > img { width:something !important; }
```

Comment: cant edit the image attributes, thats the problem. and its not just one image, thats why i would need css or javascript loop to do it. this is for a kind of userscript, i can only use javascript and css to do it